# How do results from a Python script get added to an ArcGIS map?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0

I have a Python script for ArcGIS that makes a new feature class. I can add this to ArcGIS as a new Script (without parameters), however the resulting feature class is not automatically added to the map layers. How does this happen? Here is an example of my Python script:

```
import os
import arcgisscripting

out_feat_class = 'out.shp'
workspace = r'C:\temp'

os.chdir(workspace)
gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)
gp.toolbox = 'management'
gp.workspace = workspace

# Create feature class
gp.CreateFeatureclass(workspace, out_feat_class, 'POINT')

# Add a field to it
gp.AddField(out_feat_class, 'Value', 'DOUBLE')

# Get insert cursor
rows = gp.InsertCursor(out_feat_class)
feat = rows.NewRow()

# Set attribute data
feat.SetValue('Value', 123.45)

# Set geometry
ptObj = gp.CreateObject('Point')
ptObj.x = 101.224
ptObj.y = 442.440
feat.Shape = ptObj

# Add to feature class
rows.InsertRow(feat)

# Done, clean up
del ptObj, feat, rows
```

There are no errors, a feature class is made, but it does not automatically appear in the map. I'm using ArcGIS 10.0, but I'd like this to be backwards compatible with ArcGIS 9.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your script tool parameters definitions, create a derived, output parameter and set it using [`SetParameterAsText`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000019000000) in your script.

This still depends on the **Add results of geoprocessing operations to the display** setting under **Geoprocessing-Geoprocessing Options** being checked, however.

[image: Screenshot]

(ignore the ModelBuilder part)

See also:

- [Setting script tool parameters](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00150000000n000000.htm+)
- [Using geoprocessing options to control tool execution](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00210000000q000000)

Comment: This is working well with ArcGIS 10.0, but I'm having difficulties testing this with ArcGIS 9.3. There are no error messages with SetParameterAsText, and the derived result does not make it back to the map. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a 9.3 machine to test with, so no. It *should* work on that version with this method, though.

Comment: Perhaps 9.3 requires a Feature Layer type parameter and `MakeFeatureLayer_management` instead of a Feature Class. Something you can try anyways.

Comment: True, this solution works for 9.3. I found the registry setting on this ArcGIS 9.3 test computer: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ESRI\ArcToolbox\Settings\AddOutputsToDisplay` was set to `0` and not `1`.

Comment: That checkbox should also be present in 9.3: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/using_geoprocessing_tools/controlling_tool_results.htm

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
tempLayer = "layer"
# Make a layer from the feature class
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("C:/data/mexico.gdb/cities",tempLayer)
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(tempLayer)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer, "AUTO_ARRANGE")
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

Comment: This will not work on 9.3.

Comment: Actually I use 10.0 and it worked for me. So I posted. I am sorry then